# How to read a text file into matrix form in C

Tags: c, file, matrix

Given the following text file with the following content in it

```
SpotA B C
SpotB pass D
Spotc A E F
```

How to do I break up the words into tokens and store them in a 10 x 10 matrix.
Note that if the content in the file is a matrix size with smaller than 10 x 10, I want to add the character ~ to those positions.

So far this is my code:

```
char *matrix[10][10];
int loadFileToMatrix(char *filename){
FILE *fp;
int row = 0;
int col= 0;
char *tokens;
char buffer[1000];

fp = fopen(filename,"r");
if(fp == NULL){
  perror(filename);
  return(1);
}
while((fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp))!= NULL) {
     tokens = strtok(buffer," ");
     map[row++][col++] = tokens;
}
return(0);
}
```

If some can help me figure out how to achieve my goal that would be nice. Currently, I am really confused on how to proceed.

Comment: It's difficult to help you unless you ask a *specific* question. You have shown some code but don't specify what is wrong with it and why you can't proceed. It looks like a good start. You just need to enhance it with a few things: `malloc` memory for each string, `strcpy` the `tokens` into that memory and ensure that the indexes are correct (currently no code to keep the indices valid).

Comment: The main is I dont know how to take the text file and put it into a matrix if you can help me with that would be great.

Comment: another problem is that you only read values in the matrix's main diagonal

Answer (score 2):

Just use `fscanf` to read tokens from file to buffer, then copy tokens into your the matrix `map`. You can use `fgetc` to detect if it reaches the end of line and the end of file.

```
char ch;
while (1) {
    fscanf(fp, "%s", buffer);
    matrix[row][col] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(buffer) + 1));
    strcpy(matrix[row][col], buffer);
    ch = fgetc(fp);
    if (ch == ' ') {
        col += 1;
    }
    else if (ch == '\n') {
        row += 1;
        col = 0;
    }
    else if (ch == EOF) {
        break; // end of file.
    }
}
```

Comment: @Zero The reason it doesn't work is that the given text has only three rows and three columns, but in my previous answer, the program read exactly a 10x10 matrix. I have updated my answer so that it can auto detect end of line and end of file. It does work with the give text, obviously.

Comment: It works now, the only thing I need to fix is that it read stuff from files then fills all null spots with the letter E any suggestions?

Comment: Define a constant string `char s[2] = {'E', '\0'}`, allocate memory of size `sizeof(char) * strlen(s)` for every null spots in the matrix and copy the constant string to these target positions.

Comment: Can you show me how to, I just tried 100 times and nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

strtok() is a weird function.

The key part of the man page is this:

`"On the first call to strtok() the string to be parsed should be specified in str. In each subsequent call that should parse the same string, str should be NULL."`

The reason for this is that strtok() alters the string you pass it. It searches through a string until it finds the next character that matches one of the delimiters, and then replaces that delimiter with a null terminator. If the delimiter is found at position n, internally, strtok() saves the position n+1 as the start of the rest of the string.

By calling strtok a second time with a non-null value, you are telling the function to start all over again at the start of that string, and try again to find a delimiter -- which it can never do, because it already found the first one. Instead, your second call to strtok() should pass NULL as the first argument, so each pass can bring out the next token.

If for some reason you need to call strtok() on multiple strings simultaneously, you will overwrite the internally-saved address; only the most recent call is saved properly. The reentrant function strtok_r() is useful in that situation.

If you're ever not sure how to use a function, the man pages are the best resource. You can type `man strtok` at the command line, or even just google it.

It looks like, in this case, you're using strtok() only once. This will just return the address of the first piece of the buffer, delimited by your delimiters. You need to call strtok() in a loop to get each piece in turn.